# Vector space span over real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the set be $S=\{(a,b,c)∈\mathbb{C}^{3}|b=\bar a\}$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

I am asked to find the linear span on that set. My attempt was to define the following set member: $(w,v,z)∈S$, from here follows accoring to the definition of the set: $(w,\bar w,z)∈S$.

Now I don't know if it suits the definition of span, or there is some additional work to be done.

Comment: What does "$S$ over $\mathbb R$" mean?

Comment: @Jamāl a vector space $V$ over a field $\Bbb F$ is a set $V$ (*the space itself*), an operation "*addition*" $+$ which allows us to "*add*" elements of the space, another set $\Bbb K$ which is a field, an operation "*scalar multiplication*" $\cdot$ which allows us to "*multiply*" an element of $V$ by an element of $\Bbb F$, such that these all together satisfy certain other necessary properties.  "*S over $\Bbb R$*" just states explicitly that $\Bbb R$ is the scalar field for our example.

Comment: That said, $S$ will be the span of $(1,1,0),(i,-i,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,i)$ (*recognize that these last two are not scalar multiples of one another when the scalar field is $\Bbb R$ despite them being scalar multiples of each other when the scalar field was $\Bbb C$*) and so is *four-dimensional* (*over $\Bbb R$*)

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh, i was confused whether $S$ itself is the vector space in question or it is just a set of vectors from a larger vector space since the actual field seems to be $\mathbb C$

Comment: You can explicitly specify whatever field or space you want.  For instance, the vectorspace $\Bbb R$ over the field $\Bbb Q$ (*with usual addition and multiplication*) is infinite-dimensional, meanwhile $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb R$ is one-dimensional.  Specifying the scalar field explicitly is necessary to avoid ambiguity.  Yes, it is *common* for many common examples to have the scalar field be $\Bbb R$ if the elements are easily described with $\Bbb R$, or have it be $\Bbb C$ if the elements are easily described with $\Bbb C$ and so we might tacitly assume what the field is in some cases. Not here

Comment: @JMoravitz oh i understand now, thanks.

Comment: @JMoravitz You say these four members satisfy the definition?

Comment: @JMoravitz one more thing, we say "$V$ over $\mathbb K$" to indicate that we're defining a vector space over a field $\mathbb K$ right? Then in that case, shouldn't $\text{span}(V)$ be $V$ itself since it is the largest subspace of $V$ containing $V$?

Comment: Uh, yes... in the event that $V$ itself was already a vector space then $span(V)=V$.  It seems clear from context here though that the OP was looking for a basis of the space, a minimal set of linearly independent elements whose span spans the original space.  It was admittedly poorly worded.  It is worth noting as well that the set $S$ is not a vector space over $\Bbb C$ since it wouldn't be closed under scalar multiplication.  $(1,1,0)\in S$ but $i\cdot (1,1,0)=(i,i,0)\not\in S$ since $i\neq \bar{i}=-i$

Comment: The punchline again is that $S = \{(a+bi,a-bi,c+di)\in\Bbb C^3~:~a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R\}$ requires four real numbers to describe each element in $S$.

Comment: Nobody wants to give a final answer to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but perhaps incomplete depending on the context you're working in. Certainly any $\mathbb{R}$-linear combination of vectors in $S$ would be of the form
$$
a_1(w_1,\overline{w_1},z_1) + ... + a_n(w_n,\overline{w_n},z_n) = (a_1w_1+...a_nw_n,\overline{a_1w_1+...a_nw_n},z_1+...+z_n) = (w,\overline{w},z)
$$
For some $a_1,...,a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, $w_1,...,w_n,z_1,...,z_n \in \mathbb{C}$.

So we have that
$$
\text{span}(S) = \left\{ (w,\overline{w},z)\mid w,z \in \mathbb{C}\right\}
$$
Which is as you say, although perhaps put a little more explicitly. In order to give a fuller description of the span of $S$ as a vector space over $R$, it might be helpful/more descriptive to also find a basis.

Comment: Does it mean that $(1,1,0),(i,−i,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,i)$ is not the right span?

Comment: No, the listed vectors are not the span of $S$, but a basis for the span of $S$ which is a distinction you should try to understand really well.